# What do these terms mean? $v(a) + R(h)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

In regards to the differentiability of a function at $a.$

I know that is it differentiable if the limit of $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ exists.

Then I am given the following equation, supposing $f$ is differentiable:

$f(a+h)-f(a) = h \cdot v(a) + R(h)$ with $lim_{h \to 0} \frac{R(h)}{||h||}$.

What is $v(a)$ and $R(h)$. Where did they come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing $f$ is differentiable, then you know that the limit
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$
exists. Then you can define
$$v(a)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$
which is nothing but the derivative of $f$ at $a$ and
$$R(h)=f(a+h)-f(a)-v(a) \cdot h$$
which is called remainder.

With these definitions in mind, you can see that
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{R(h)}{h}=0$$

Comment: im confused about the remainder part. is there something i could search to read up on this part more?

Comment: The idea is that $$f(a+h) \sim f(a) + v(a) \cdot h$$ in other words in a neighbourhood of $a$ the function can be approximated witha  linear function. $R(h)$ is just the error term, which is small when $h$ is small.

Comment: so v(a) = lim$ \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}$ and removing the limit makes them approximately equal such that

$0 \approx f(a+h)-f(a)-h\cdot v(a)$

then its equivalent by making left hand side  R(h)

$R(h) \approx f(a+h) - f(a) - h \cdot v(a)$

why do i need these terms to define a function as differentiable

Comment: that is if my understanding is right, why cant i just use the v(a) = definition to say a function is differentiable. why do i need to include terms such as $h \cdot v(a)$ and R(h)

Comment: These are just definitions that will be useful later, when you'll continue studying differentiability.